# PHP - Understanding timestamp argument (usage records)

Tags: php, stripe-payments, unix-timestamp

I'm trying to setup upcoming invoices for metered billing from stripe. In order to do this I need to run usage records. My understanding is that a Usage record will need to run in order to generate an accurate upcoming invoice. I created a function called `stripeUsageRecord()` that I call before generating the invoice.

```
  public function stripeUsageRecord()
  {
    $authUser = auth()->user();
    $sub_item = $authUser['subscription_item'];
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(env("STRIPE_SECRET"));
    return \Stripe\UsageRecord::create(array(
      "quantity" => 11,
      // "timestamp" => time(),
      "timestamp" => 1540225312,
      "subscription_item" => $sub_item,
      "action" => "set"
    ));
  }
```

This function does do its desired outcome. The only problem I am running into is that I cannot set the timestamp dynamically. If I run a static timestamp (within the subscription date range) it works the way I want it to, which is not increment it. but If i use the php `time()` to set the time stamp to the current time it increments the quantity (when I need it to be updating it).

(In my code the quantity is determined by a query which counts all the users that have shopped at the location within the subscription time frame. here I just add a number so it would be easier to understand.)

how can I set the timestamp dynamically updating the quantity instead of adding it on top of the previous usage record ran with a different time stamp?

Comment: I don't know a thing about this API, but if you want to update something, shouldn't you not be using a function called `create()`? And if you're having trouble with some code, post it. Don't "just add a number" to the part of your code that doesn't work.

Comment: `set` will overwrite the usage quantity at a given timestamp. If the new record you create has a different timestamp, you're right, it will just add to the total to be charged at the end of period rather than overwriting. You could set the underlying plan with the option `aggregate_usage=last_during_period` so that only the last record for the timestamp is used on the final invoice

Comment: @duck you were correct. Made those changes and it worked. If you add that as the answer I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a `UsageRecord`, `set` will overwrite the usage quantity at a given timestamp. If the new record you create has a different timestamp, it will just add to the total to be charged at the end of period rather than overwriting.

The way to work around this is you could set-up the underlying plan with the option `aggregate_usage=last_during_period`, so that only the last record for the timestamp is used on the final invoice!

Something like this:

```
\Stripe\Plan::create(array(
  "amount" => 100,
  "interval" => "month",
  "product" => array(
    "name" => "Gold Metered"
  ),
  "currency" => "usd",
  "id" => "gold-metered",
  "usage_type" => "metered",
  "aggregate_usage" => "last_during_period"
));
```

More context is here:
https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/metered-billing#reporting-usage